# word2vec training procedure clarification

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to learn the skip-gram model within word2vec, however I'm confused by some of the basic concepts.  To start, here is my current understanding of the model motivated with an example.  I am using Python [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) as I go.

Here I have a corpus with three sentences.

```
sentences = [
    ['i', 'like', 'cats', 'and', 'dogs'],
    ['i', 'like', 'dogs'],
    ['dogs', 'like', 'dogs']
]
```

From this, I can determine my vocabulary, `V = ['and', 'cats', 'dogs', 'i', 'like']`.

Following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf) by Tomas Mikolov (and others)

> The basic Skip-gram formulation defines p(w_t+j |w_t) using the softmax
>   function:

[image: skipgram]

> where v_w and v′_w are the “input” and “output” vector representations
>   of w, and W is the number of words in the vocabulary.

To my understanding, the skip-gram model involves two matrices (I'll call them *I* and *O*) which are the vector representations of "input/center" words and the vector representation of "output/context" words.  Assuming d = 2 (vector dimension or 'size' as its called in genism), *I* should be a 2x5 matrix and *O* should be a 5x2 matrix.  At the start of the training procedure, these matrices are filled with random values (yes?).  So we might have

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2017)

I = np.random.rand(5,2).round(2)  # 5 rows by 2 cols
[[ 0.02  0.77] # and
 [ 0.45  0.12] # cats
 [ 0.93  0.65] # dogs
 [ 0.14  0.23] # i
 [ 0.23  0.26]] # like

O = np.random.rand(2,5).round(2)  # 2 rows by 5 cols
  #and  #cats #dogs  #i   #like 
[[ 0.11  0.63  0.39  0.32  0.63]
 [ 0.29  0.94  0.15  0.08  0.7 ]]
```

Now if I want to calculate the probability that the word "dogs" appears in the context of "cats" I should do

exp([0.39, 0.15] * [0.45  0.12])/(...) = (0.1125)/(...)

A few questions on this:

1. Is my understanding of the algorithm correct thus far?
2. Using genism, I can train a model on this data using

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, sg = 1, size=2, window=1, min_count=1)
model.wv['dogs']  # array([ 0.06249372,  0.22618999], dtype=float32)
```

For the array given, is that the vector for "dogs" in the Input matrix or the Output matrix?  Is there a way to view both matrices in the final model?

3. Why does `model.wv.similarity('cats','cats')` = 1?  I thought this should be closer to 0, since the data would indicate that the word "cats" is unlikely to occur in the context of the word "cats".

Comment: According to Richard Socher in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASn7ExxLZws) around 41:00 - 42:30, the final *input* and *output* vectors are typically added together to generate a final vector for each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Generally, yes, but:

The *O* output matrix – more properly understood as the weights from the neural-network's hidden layer, to a number of output nodes – is interpreted differently whether using 'negative sampling' ('NS') or 'hierarchical softmax' ('HS') training.

In practice in both *I* and *O* are *len(vocab)* rows and *vector-size* columns. (*I* is the `Word2Vec` `model` instance's `model.wv.syn0` array; *O* is its `model.syn1neg` array in NS or `model.syn1` in HS.)

I find NS a bit easier to think about: each predictable word corresponds to a single output node. For training data where (context)-indicates->(word), training tries to drive that word's node value toward 1.0, and the other randomly-chosen word node values toward 0.0.

In HS, each word is represented by a huffman-code of a small subset of the output nodes – those 'points' are driven to 1.0 or 0.0 to make the network more indicative of a single word after a (context)-indicates->(word) example.

Only the *I* matrix, initial word values, are randomized to low-magnitude vectors at the beginning. (The hidden-to-output weights *O* are left zeros.)

(2) Yes, that'll train things - just note that tiny toy-sized examples won't necessarily generate the useful constellations-of-vector-coordinates that are valued from word2vec.

(3) Note, `model.similarity('cats', 'cats')` is actually checking the cosine-similarity between the (input) vectors for those two words. Those are the same word, thus they definitionally have the same vector, and the similarity between identical vectors is 1.0.

That is, `similarity()` is *not* asking the model for a prediction, it's retrieving learned words by key and comparing those vectors. (Recent versions of gensim do have a `predict_output_word()` function, but it only works in NS mode, and making predictions isn't really the point of word2vec, and many implementations don't offer any prediction API at all. Rather, the point is using those attempted predictions during training to induce word-vectors that turn out to be useful for various other tasks.)

But even if you were reading predictions, 'cats' might still be a reasonable-although-bad prediction from the model in the context of 'cats'. The essence of forcing large vocabularies into the smaller dimensionality of 'dense' embeddings is compression – the model has no choice but to cluster related words together, because there's not enough internal complexity (learnable parameters) to simply memorize all details of the input. (And for the most part, that's a good thing, because it results in generalizable patterns, rather than just overfit idiosyncrasies of the training corpus.)

The word 'cats' will wind up close to 'dogs' and 'pets' – because they all co-occur with similar words, or each other. And thus the model will be forced to make similar output-predictions for each, because their input-vectors don't vary that much. And a few predictions that are nonsensical in logical language use – like a repeating word - may be made, but only because taking a larger error there still gives less error over the whole training set, compared to other weighting alternatives.